# OCaml How to write into file?

Tags: file, file-io, io, ocaml

I'm looking for a way to write two `int`s to a file. There will be many pairs of two `int`s. Between the two numbers there should be a space (I mean ''). For example, something like this:

```
1 2
6 896
243 865
....
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use something like this:

```
let rec print_numbers oc = function 
  | [] -> ()
  | e::tl -> Printf.fprintf oc "%d %d\n" (fst e) (snd e); print_numbers oc tl

let () =
  let nums = [(1, 2); (6, 896); (243, 865)] in
  let oc = open_out "filename.txt" in
  print_numbers oc nums;
  close_out oc;
```

This assumes your data is a list of pairs.

Answer (score 6):

If you use [`Core`](https://github.com/janestreet/core), you can do this:

```
open Core.Std
let () = Out_channel.write_all "your_file.txt" ~data:"Your text"
```